# How to get a value in JSON by an id value in the class in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, fetch

I want to get the "temp" value inside the "weather" array of a city that i search with the "name" of the city.
I did it with a for loop but it slow, is there another better way to do it?

Here is the JSON file: https://ws.smn.gob.ar/map_items/weather

Here is my code so far:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}

fun fetchJson(view:View){
    println("attemting to fetch JSON")

    val url = "https://ws.smn.gob.ar/map_items/weather"

    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            var body = response?.body()?.string()

            println(body)

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

            val cities = gson.fromJson<List<Cities>>(body, object : TypeToken<List<Cities>>() {}.type)

            for(city in cities){
                if(city.name.equals(nameOfCity.text.toString())){
                    showsTemp.text = city.weather.temp.toString()
                }}



        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Se fallo en establecer la comunicacion")
        }

    })

}

class Cities(val _id:String,
         val name:String,
         val province:String,
         val weather: Weather)
class Weather(val humidity: Int,val temp: Double)
```

}

Comment: Why don't you try `Klaxon` ? I think it's faster than `GSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use `list.find{}` for finding a city with its name without looping.

Here in your code it should be like this.

```
val cities = gson.fromJson<List<Cities>>(body, object : TypeToken<List<Cities>>() {}.type)
val cityFounded = cities.find{ it.name == nameOfCity.text.toString() }
showsTemp.text = cityFounded?.weather?.temp.toString()
```

Hope it will help you.